# Kendo dropdownlist with input textbox not responding as expected in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, telerik, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-dropdown

I want to create a google search kind of Dropdownlist with Kendo Angular. But if I enter some input in the textbox and press "Enter" the first matching value is getting passed to my component instead of the input textbox value.

**Component.html:**

```
<kendo-dropdownlist 
 (selectionChange)="OnListSelectionChange($event)"
 (filterChange)="OnListChange($event)"
 [data]="InputList"
 [filterable]="true"
 textField="Name"
 valueField="Code"
 [(ngModel)]="InputListObject">
```

**Component.ts**
This Action invokes in input keypress event

```
OnListChange(ip)
{
    if(ip.length > 0)
    {
        this.selectedInputValue = ip;
        this.InputListObject = undefined;

        //Service call to fetch list of matching values
        return InputList = service.data;
    }
    else
    {
        this.selectedInputValue  = undefined;
    }
}
```

This Action invokes in dropdown value selection event and textbox enter button event

```
OnListSelectionChange(ip)
{
//ip will always have the first matching value from the dropdown list even on the textbox enter button event.

    if(this.selectedInputValue != undefined)     //If I have some input in textbox
    {
        GetSearchData(this.selectedInputValue);
    }
    else                       //If no input and I select some value from the dropdown
        GetSearchData(ip);
}
```

I want to distinguish between both the events because this logic gets fail if I type some input in the input textbox and then select any value from the dropdown.

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you only want drop down value when click on that option only ?

Answer (score 0):

You want a ComboBox, not a DropDownList

A DropDownList as a fixed Set of which you can select one. The filter is used to limit the visible options, but does not function as an extra value.

Using a ComboBox allows you to select from an exisiting list of values, but also enter a new value!

best regards
Jimmy